# when reading a javascript file with java's scriptengine functions in the file that interact with other objects in the file don't work

Tags: javascript, java, scope, undefined-reference, scriptengine

I am making a basic 2d game engine that uses java for all basic engine operations and javascript for game specific operations. In the javascript file i have a tick function that is called by my java logic thread;

```js
    tick = function(){print(keyBinds[i].getState()}
```

the keyBinds object is defined in the global scope in the file

```
    keyBinds = [ new keyEvent('A', false), new keyEvent('ENTER', false)...
```

i know that the keyBind object works because in the javafx stage thread i use the object to setup the keylistener
the problem is that when i call the tick function I get this

error
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call undefined in  at line number 46

in java I set up the engine with this

```
    InputStream b = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/script.js");
        Reader a = new InputStreamReader(b);
        engine.eval(a);
        js = (Invocable)engine;
```

and I call the tick function with this

```
    return js.invokeFunction("tick");
```

anyone know why the javascript functions can't see any of the objects defined in the same file.